MS Word: How to create a grid with many small checkboxes
Please check this image. I want to create the same template but I don’t know how to create this grid. I tried with a table 52x88 but it doesn‘t look good. Any other ideas?


https://sheet.new/ and then import it

In your post, please include a screenshot of your current table. Otherwise we won't be able to see where something might have gone wrong.
My guess is, that you didn't decrease the font size within the table or you didn't remove the paragraph spacing or you didn't remove the cell margins. In case you don't know what that means, please have a look at the video about changing cell paddings.
But to summarize the step you should take:
Select whole table and:

Set font size to 1pt
Set paragraph spacing before and after to 0pt
Set cell margins to 0
Set column width to desired width (e.g. 0.5cm)
Set row height to desired height (e.g. 0.5cm)
In the cell-margin dialog, check the box for allowing spacing between cells. This will create a nice look in which the cells have space in between them

When you are done, it should look something like that:

Of course, you can customize this now to make some columns wider and remove their border to create a gap-effect.

Sorry, I have no current version. I wanna create the same design like the image provided. There is a gap after every 4 columns for example. I am not sure how he/she made it. Could it be that this template is not made in Word?

@Haidepzai It can very well be that the template hasn't been created in Word. There are a multitude of softwares out there with which you can design such things. And Word is one of them. The gap after every 4 columns can also be created in Word. Simply remove the borders of every 5th column and that column will then serve as a gap.
